# How to set up WiFi connection on a MacBook (early 2008)/Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: wireless, connection, macbook

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The system works OK but I can't get a wireless Internet connection. So far, I can only get a wired connection (about 50 cm from the modem).

I went through various help topics requesting to install some drivers but nothing worked. I thought I could set the wireless connection manually but I can't find any clear and/or relevant documentation about it. Any suggestion?
Or could you suggest another Ubuntu version that would possibly solve the problem for my computer?

And please don't tell me to get a longer cable! Thx ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree

sudo modprobe b43

dmesg |grep -e b43 -e bcma

from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2011756

Comment: Sorry, but I can't manage to type the pipe...

Comment: OK, I found it.

Comment: Prompted to download some firmware updates but can't access the site. I'll try again later.

Answer (score 0):

This method shows promise, but after a couple of reboots the device can't locate networks.

I've been trying for 3 days now to get my wifi to work on MacAir 2008 1, 1 of which has a broadcom wifi device BCM4321 PCI_14e4_4328. Absolutely none of the advice garnered from researching worked for me. But doing the following which I pieced together from different sources worked.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Then the next part is not particularly user-friendly but easy enough: 
Download a backport from [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/?C=M;O=D). If you select last modified to get the latest on top choose that. Download the build and copy it to a USB stick. Then copy it to your home directory `~/Desktop` or `~/Documents` doesn't matter then `sudu su` to be root, enter the directory you unzipped and do a make install, it will show and error but it gives you a clue what to do. Can't remember now, but I think it said `make oldConfig` it's one of the two notices you get at the beginning.

Here is the link to some [instructions to build the backports and install](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/?C=M;O=D).

Getting the backports installed is the key to successfully configuring your wifi device.

Comment: I would recommend adding in the essential instructions from the links referenced. This makes the information easier to get, as it keeps it in one place, and makes sure that the information is always readily available, even if the website linked goes down or changes.

Comment: Actually, as of now, it is unreliable, it worked at first, couple of reboots later it no longer sees networks again. However, this course of action has promise but need to figure out to keep it stable.

Comment: Good to know, can you please add that as a disclaimer at the top of your answer?

Comment: Done. A work in progress will post back here if successful with full instructions.